# Sklearn and StatsModels give very different logistic regression answers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am doing logistic regression on a boolean 0/1 dataset (predicting the probability of a certain age giving you a salary over some amount), and I am getting very different results with sklearn and StatsModels, where sklearn is very *wrong*.

I have set the sklearn penalty to None and the intercept term to false to make the function more similar to StatsModels, but I can't see how to make sklearn give a sensible answer.

The grey lines are the original datapoints at 0 or 1, I just scaled 1 down to 0.1 on the plot to be visible.

Variables:

```
# X and Y
X = df.age.values.reshape(-1,1)
X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4).fit_transform(X)
y_bool = np.array(df.wage.values > 250, dtype = "int")

# Generate a sequence of ages
age_grid = np.arange(X.min(), X.max()).reshape(-1,1)
age_grid_poly =  PolynomialFeatures(degree=4).fit_transform(age_grid)
```

Code is the following:

```
# sklearn Model
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty = None, fit_intercept = False,max_iter = 300).fit(X=X_poly, y=y_bool)
preds = clf.predict_proba(age_grid_poly)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.scatter(X ,y_bool/10, s=30, c='grey', marker='|', alpha=0.7)
plt.plot(age_grid, preds[:,1], color = 'r', alpha = 1)
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Wage')
plt.show()
```

[sklearn result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqjg7.png)

```
# StatsModels
log_reg = sm.Logit(y_bool, X_poly).fit()
preds = log_reg.predict(age_grid_poly)
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.scatter(X ,y_bool/10, s=30, c='grey', marker='|', alpha=0.7)
plt.plot(age_grid, preds, color = 'r', alpha = 1)
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Wage')
plt.show()
```

[StatsModels result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1FYC.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be because of sklearn's implementation being very scale-dependent (and the polynomial terms being quite large).  By scaling the data first, I get qualitatively the same result.

```py
# sklearn Model
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

clf = Pipeline([
    ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('lr', LogisticRegression(penalty='none', fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000)),
]).fit(X=X_poly, y=y_bool)
preds = clf.predict_proba(age_grid_poly)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.scatter(X ,y_bool/10, s=30, c='grey', marker='|', alpha=0.7)
plt.plot(age_grid, preds[:,1], color = 'r', alpha = 1)
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Wage')
plt.show()
```

Note that we need to set `fit_intercept=True` in this case, because the `StandardScaler` kills the constant column (making it all zeros) coming from the `PolynomialFeatures`.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't reproduce exactly the results once I don't have the dataset or the specific versions of the scikit-learn and statsmodels. However, I don't think you were able to successfully removing the regularization parameter in your code. The documentation states that you should pass the string `'none'`, not the constant `None`.

Please, refer to [sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) documentation:

> **penalty{‘l1’, ‘l2’, ‘elasticnet’, ‘none’}, default=’l2’** Used to
> specify the norm used in the penalization. The ‘newton-cg’, ‘sag’ and
> ‘lbfgs’ solvers support only l2 penalties. ‘elasticnet’ is only
> supported by the ‘saga’ solver. If ‘none’ (not supported by the
> liblinear solver), no regularization is applied.

I think it is easier to understand the difference by investigating the coefficient, instead of using a plot.
You can investigate it directly using the property `coef_` for the scikit-learn model and `params` for the statsmodels model.

In logical terms, you should expect the coefficient to be lower in the scikit-learn model if the regularization parameter is not properly disabled.

Comment: I have tried both with penalty = 'none' and a very large C value, but I still get the same plot. The coefficients do look suspiciously regularised though for sklearn - statsmodel has the largest coeff around 200, while sklearn has 0.02  
  

(sklearn version 0.24.0, statsmodels version 0.12.1, dataset [here](https://github.com/JWarmenhoven/ISLR-python/blob/master/Notebooks/Data/Wage.csv) if you are interested)

Comment: This might being caused by the assumptions that each implementation use to deal with the non-linearity generated by the polynomial features.

I've tried to experiment both models only the age as IV and set up all the other circumstances below, and the result was a similar coefficients:
LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs', penalty = 'none', fit_intercept = False, max_iter = 300).fit(X = X, y = y_bool)
Logit(y_bool, X).fit(method = 'lbfgs', maxiter=300, full_output=0, disp=0)