# LogisticRegression from sk_learn and smf.logit() from statsmodels.formula.api return different results

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I am trying to calculate the variance of the coefficients for logistic regression using bootstrap and I am using scikit-learn and statsmodels to compare results. I am using the Default dataset from the
[ISLR](https://www.statlearning.com/resources-first-edition) website which can be found in the zip forlder [here](https://www.statlearning.com/s/ALL-CSV-FILES-1st-Edition.zip) or [here](https://github.com/dsnair/ISLR/blob/master/data/csv/Default.csv) as a plain csv file.
I am using the following codes to perform the bootstrap:

Import the Dataset and create the response variable

```
default_df = pd.read_csv("./Machine-Learning-Books-With-Python/Introduction to Statistical Learning/data/default.csv")

default_df['default_01'] = np.where(default_df.default == 'Yes', 1, 0)
```

Next, I am defining the *boot* function which will take care of the random sampling for my dataset:

```
def boot(X, bootSample_size=None):
    '''
    Sampling observations from a dataframe

    Parameters
    ------------
    X : pandas dataframe
        Data to be resampled

    bootSample_size: int, optional
        Dimension of the bootstrapped samples

    Returns
    ------------
    bootSample_X : pandas dataframe
                   Resampled data

    Examples
    ----------
    To resample data from the X dataframe:
        >> boot(X)
    The resampled data will have length equal to len(X).

    To resample data from the X dataframe in order to have length 5:
        >> boot(X,5)

    References
    ------------
    http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/aflaxman/6871948

    '''
    #assign default size if non-specified
    if bootSample_size == None:
        bootSample_size = len(X)

    #create random integers to use as indices for bootstrap sample based on original data
    bootSample_i = (np.random.rand(bootSample_size)*len(X)).astype(int)
    bootSample_i = np.array(bootSample_i)
    bootSample_X = X.iloc[bootSample_i]

    return bootSample_X
```

Finally, I define two functions that will perform the logistic regression and extract the parameters:

Using **statsmodels**

```
def boot_fn(data):
    lr = smf.logit(formula='default_01 ~ income + balance', data=data).fit(disp=0)
    return lr.params
```

Using **scikit-learn**

```
def boot_fn2(data):
    X = data[['income', 'balance']]
    y = data.default_01
    logit = LogisticRegression(C = 1e9)
    logit.fit(X, y)
    return logit.coef_
```

Finally the loop to run the functions 100 times and store the results:

```
coef_sk = []
coef_sm = []
for _ in np.arange(100):
    data = boot(default_df)
    coef_sk.append(boot_fn2(data))
    coef_sm.append(boot_fn(data))
```

Taking the mean for both coef_sk (scikit-learn) and coef_sm (statsmodels) I see that the one generated using statsmodels is much closer to the real value and also for different runs the scikit-learn coefficients appear to diverge quite a lot from the actual value. Could you please explain why this happens? I find it very confusing since I would expect that for the same datasets, results should be the same (at least marginally different). However, in this case, results differ a lot, which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the way I am running the sk-learn version. Would appreciate any help and I would be more than happy to provide additional clarifications.

Comment: What happens if you remove C = 1e9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you set the C parameter to be high to minimize, sklearn by default uses `lbfgs` solver to find your optimal parameters while statsmodels uses `newton` .

You can try doing this to get similar coefficients:

```
def boot_fn2(data):
    X = data[['income', 'balance']]
    y = data.default_01
    logit = LogisticRegression(penalty="none",max_iter=1000,solver = "newton-cg")
    logit.fit(X, y)
    return logit.coef_
```

If I run this with the above function:

```
coef_sk = []
coef_sm = []
for _ in np.arange(50):
    data = boot(default_df)
    coef_sk.append(boot_fn2(data))
    coef_sm.append(boot_fn(data))
```

You will instantly see that it throws a lot of warnings about being unable to converge:

```
LineSearchWarning: The line search algorithm did not converge
```

Although the coefficients are similar now, it points to a larger issue with your dataset, similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66830858/sklearn-and-statsmodels-give-very-different-logistic-regression-answers)

```
np.array(coef_sm)[:,1:].mean(axis=0)
array([2.14570133e-05, 5.68280785e-03])

np.array(coef_sk).mean(axis=0)
array([[2.14352318e-05, 5.68116402e-03]])
```

Your dependent variables are quite huge and this poses a problem for the optimization methods available in sklearn. You can just scale two of your dependent variables down if you want to interpret the coefficients:

```
default_df[['balance','income']] = default_df[['balance','income']]/100
```

Else it's always a good practice to scale your independent variables first and apply the regression:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
default_df[['balance','income']] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(default_df[['balance','income']])

def boot_fn(data):
    lr = smf.logit(formula='default_01 ~ income + balance', data=data).fit(disp=0)
    return lr.params
def boot_fn2(data):
    X = data[['income', 'balance']]
    y = data.default_01
    logit = LogisticRegression(penalty="none")
    logit.fit(X, y)
    return logit.coef_

coef_sk = []
coef_sm = []
for _ in np.arange(50):
    data = boot(default_df)
    #print(data.default_01.mean())
    coef_sk.append(boot_fn2(data))
    coef_sm.append(boot_fn(data))
```

Now you'll see the coefficients are similar:

```
np.array(coef_sm)[:,1:].mean(axis=0)    
array([0.26517582, 2.71598194])

np.array(coef_sk).mean(axis=0)
array([[0.26517504, 2.71598548]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and quick answer!